# How do I remove a User from a Teams Shared Channel if they are not a member of a certain security group?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to automate the removal of users from a shared channel that are not part of a dynamic security group. I think I'm heading down the right path, but I'm relatively new to PS scripting.

```
$securitygroupId = "The Security Group"
$channelgroupId = "The GroupId of the host AzureAD Group"
$channelname = "Name of the Shared Channel"

Get-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $channelgroupId -DisplayName $channelname |
    ForEach-Object {$channelusergroups = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $_.UserId | Select ObjectId
                    if ($channelusergroups -NotContains $securitygroupId)
                        {Remove-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $channelgroupId -DisplayName $channelname -User $_.User
                        }
                   }
```

It removes the users right now even if they are in the security group.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that if you put "-expand" after "select", the search will find the ObjectId of the security group in the pipeline. Hope this helps someone else!
-Cheers